# VBA error in data validation: Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this following code

```
Set works1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set works2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rangeval1 = works1.Cells(11 , 4)
Set rangeval2 = works2.Range("j322:j325")

With rangeval1.Validation
   .Delete 
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="='" & works2.name & "'!" & rangeval2.Address          "Line with the error"

 End With
```

I am unable to figure out what the error is, becoz the code seems correct to me

Comment: Which version of Excel? Excel 2007 and earlier do not allow direct references to other worksheets in data validation - you have to name the range.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. The problem is you need to active the sheet that you want to create validation and select it. The most important thing is you need to select at the range which you want to create validation.

```
currentSheet.Activate
currentSheet.Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert

currentSheet.Cells("C3").Select

With currentSheet.Cells("C3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, 
    Formula1:="A,B,C,D"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .errorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure your sheet is NOT protected, if so Unprotect the sheet and try again, it will work!

Comment: that was it for me, none of the other answers mention it. a simple check to see if the worksheet is protected to unprotect it and protect it back after did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a comma after operator. It should be Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, **Operator:=xlBetween,** Formula1:="='" & works2.name & "'!" & rangeval2.Address. Please let me know

It fetches me the value from sheet2 as dropdown[image: Sheet 2]

[image: Sheet1]

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=("='" & works2.Name & "'!" & rangeval2.Address)
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    Sub start()
Set works1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set works2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rangeval1 = works1.Cells(11, 4)
Set rangeval2 = works2.Range("d2:d5")

With rangeval1.Validation
   .Delete
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=("='" & works2.Name & "'!" & rangeval2.Address)

 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to put the comma in the question but its there in my code in the VBA editor but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Gajju : If you have "option explicit" statement at the top, remove it and then try to run your code. Let me know

Comment: The sheet in which I have written the code, I  haven't written `Option Explicit` at top

Comment: @Gajju : Thats wierd. It should. I am using ur code as per my latest update (Check answer) and i have placed it in sheet2. Check and let me know. Chnage the range value alone. Also makes sure refrences are made to Excel library

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Sriram's answer isn't working for you.

The following works for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim works1 As Worksheet
    Dim works2 As Worksheet
    Dim rangeval1 As Range
    Dim rangeval2 As Range

    Set works1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set works2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rangeval1 = works1.Cells(11, 4)
    Set rangeval2 = works2.Range("j322:j325")

    With rangeval1.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, _
            Formula1:="='" & works2.Name & "'!" & rangeval2.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice the Option Explicit at the top, then the declaring of each variable with a type. You may have this in your code already. But hard to tell with what you posted in your question.

If that still doesn't work, check to see if your sheets are really named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

A bug I've just found, You cannot change the validation with VBA's `Add` method if the current Excel Selection is a Chart.

This might have been the issue that you were facing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and the problem was that it worked first time but not any subsequent times. The issue was that I was trying to add validation (.Validation.Add) to a cell that already had a list validation on it. I had to stick in a line to clear the validation (.Validation.Delete) before it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error just now and after spending close to half an hour on it,

I found that I had checked "R1C1 reference style" in the Options- Formulas- Working with formulas

As soon as I unchecked that option, everything started working fine again.